# How do you run a single PHP instance with CRON?

Tags: php, cron

I'm having trouble running a single instance of a PHP script using CRON. Perhaps someone can help explain what is needed. Currenty, I have a `startup` script that is called by `crontab` which checks to make sure an instance of a PHP script isn't already running before calling the PHP instance.

`crontab -e` entry:

```
* * * * * /var/www/private/script.php >> /var/www/private/script.log 2>&1 &
```

./startup

```
#!/bin/bash

if ps -ef | grep '[s]cript';
        then
                exit;
        else
                /usr/bin/php /var/www/private/script.php  >>/var/www/private/script.log 2>&1 &
                echo 'started'
fi
```

This doesn't seem to be working and I can't seem to get any errors logged to know how to proceed to debug this.

Comment: Have you tried running `/usr/bin/nohup php /var/www/private/script.php >>/var/www/private/script.log 2>&1 &` in terminal directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lockrun for that: http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile=/var/run/script.lockrun -- php /home/script.php
```

Or use Perl:

```
system('php /home/script.php') if ( ! `ps -aef|grep -v grep|grep script.php`);
```

Comment: Sounds a no proper solution. It's quite not **atomic**

Answer (score 0):

Testing processes is not the most reliable way to prevent multiple instance of a script.

In `bash`, I recommend you to use that :

```
if ( set -o noclobber; echo "locked" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
  trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
  echo "Locking succeeded" >&2
  rm -f "$lockfile"
else
  echo "Lock failed - exit" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

There's another examples in this page http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex

**Another solution** (if not using `NFS`) is to use `flock (1)`, see [How do I use the linux flock command to prevent another root process from deleting a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040828/how-do-i-use-the-linux-flock-command-to-prevent-another-root-process-from-deleti)