# run single apache2 request from sh file

Tags: php, bash, cron, apache2, sh

I have used a script to perform a cron job as follow

```
    URL="http://local.cloudservice.com/process2"
    LOG="/var/www/cloudservice/logs/cs.log"
    DATETIME=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S")
    echo "Started at $DATETIME"

    if [[ `ps aux | grep $URL | wc -l` > 1 ]]; 
    then
        echo "$DATETIME : Exitting -> More than one Processing" >> $LOG
        exit 0
    fi

    for RETRY in $(seq 1 100); 

        do
            echo "$DATETIME : Running" >> $LOG
            if [ $(curl -s --connect-timeout 60 --max-time 300 $URL | grep -cim1 "Job queue is empty\|wtf" ) == "1" ]; 
            
            then
                echo "$DATETIME : Processed"  >> $LOG
                exit 0
            else
                echo "$DATETIME : Currently Busy - sleeping " >> $LOG
                sleep 1
            fi
        done

    exit 0

    DATETIME=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S")
    echo "Ended at $DATETIME"
```

I have used this file in every minute cron. Here I am trying to stop a cron if the request is already processing on that url. But I feel like the 2 request is sometimes running regardless of grepping it.

Here is the log

[image: log]]

The code to produce this is

```
    <?php
    
    //a working function inside some class say Processor class
    public function linkSmartColAndProduct($shop, &$processed, &$additional_info){
        $reference_temp = $processed;
        try{
            sleep(3);
            
            //code here
            
            // lots of db operation. this db operations is not related with increasing the processed count db operation any way
            
            $processed ++;
            $additional_info = "some text value";
            if(true) //some condition matches
                return true;
            //else return false
            return false;
        }catch(Exception $e){
             error_log("Log:" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    //Another function inside some other class say Jobs, calling above function
    
    public function process2(){
        $data = //gets value from db consists shop_id, processed, additional_info
        $processor = new Processor();
        $processor->linkSmartColAndProduct($data->shop_id,$data->processed, $data->additional_info); //calling the above function
        $data->update(); // updating the db after the value is changed from above function linkSmartColAndProduct
    }
```

According to the expected code, processed value should have increased, for each cron job, but some times it is duplicated as you can see in picture, processed count 170 and 170
Is my sh file written correctly to block the request? Or is it due to the db operation the other processes are executing ?

Any kinds of insight and suggestion are highly appreciated. Thanks
PS: I have already looked into, [How do you run a single PHP instance with CRON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902996/how-do-you-run-a-single-php-instance-with-cron)

**Edit**

Also the log from sh file says the process is restricted

```
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Running
    2020.09.16-20:08:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:09:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:10:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:11:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:12:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Currently Busy - sleeping 
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Running
    2020.09.16-20:13:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:14:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:15:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:16:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:17:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Currently Busy - sleeping 
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Running
    2020.09.16-20:18:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:19:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:20:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:21:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-20:22:01 : Exitting -> More than one Processing
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Currently Busy - sleeping 
    2020.09.16-19:52:01 : Running
```

Comment: Couple things that will help you get more view, comments and answers.  **1** Provide a [mcve] in your question. **2** Read [ask].  **3** indentation in your bash script is critical to clear understanding.  **4** https://www.shellcheck.net/ will help you debug your bash scripts.  **5** read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These, do not use `seq` to count.  **6 And finaly** read this one about having only one instance running at the same time: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045

Comment: @Nic3500 Sure. Thank you.