# How to lock a file in linux/unix by a java program?

Tags: java, linux, file-locking

I need to lock a file in unix/linux OS. I have googled and read about `java.nio.channels Filelock` and `Reentrant File Lock` . But both works in Windows but not in unix. Is there any other way of implementing a lock on file in unix? Any sample code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vignesh

Comment: is there any way to do a file lock other than java.nio.channels filelock?

Comment: As per this link `Unix locks are ADVISORY`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040828/how-do-i-use-the-linux-flock-command-to-prevent-another-root-process-from-deleti

Comment: Could you explain more about the requirement. What kind of lock you want. Do you want to prevent your file from being deleted or do you want to lock your file so no other process can write/read it?

Comment: i need a lock that can prevent other process from read write operation

Comment: There is no such thing; locks are _advisory_. If the other process does not cooperate by using the same locking primitives/methods as your process does, it can access the file all it wants and there is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: "but not in unix[sic]" this statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

you could have a look at this (not java related) post - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20104/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-deletion-of-certain-files-from-user-owned-directory.

it contains 2 solutions - either chowning the file by root and setting the sticky bit or using ext2/3/4 specific attributes.

both of these solutions are doable from java using System.exec()